# $\vert f(z)\vert=\exp{(\vert g(z)\vert)}$ implies $g\equiv0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f,g\in H(\mathbb{D})$ ($f,g$ holomorphic on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$) , $g(0)=0$ and $\vert f(z)\vert=\exp{(\vert g(z)\vert)}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$. Show that $g\equiv0$ on $\mathbb{D}$ and that there exists an $\eta\in\partial\mathbb{D}$ with $f\equiv\eta$ on $\mathbb{D}$.

The statement about $f$ is trivial once one proved that $g\equiv0$, but I am unable to prove that.
I defined $h(z):=\frac{g(z)}{f(z)}$ and since $\vert g(z)\vert<\exp{(\vert g(z)\vert)}$ it follows $$h(z):\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$$ because $\vert h(z)\vert=\frac{\vert g(z)\vert}{\vert \exp{\vert g(z)\vert }\vert}<1$. Since $\vert h(0)\vert =\frac{0}{1}=0$ I can apply Schwarz Lemma on $h$ what gives me $\vert h(z)\vert = \frac{\vert g(z)\vert}{\vert f(z)\vert}\leq\vert z\vert$ and $\vert h'(0)\vert\leq1$. Because of $h'(z)=\frac{f(z)g'(z)-g(z)f'(z)}{f(z)^2}$ it follows $h'(0)=\frac{g'(0)}{f(0)}$, so it follows $\vert g'(0)\vert\leq \vert f(0)\vert$

But at this point I am stuck, I am unable to prove that $g\equiv0$ on $\mathbb{D}$. Obviously it would be enough to show that $g\equiv$ const since I know $g(0)=0$.

I would be thankful for any hint how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [minimum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle#Minimum_modulus_principle): Since
$$0<1=|f(0)|=\exp(|g(0)|)\leq \exp(|g(z)|)=|f(z)|,$$
it follows from the principle that $f$ is constant and thus also $g$ is constant.